# Как передать значения из дочернего окна в главное?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.
Есть главное окно, в котором работает пользователь, и при
необходимости изменять какие-либо
данные он нажимает кнопку
редактировать и создаётся новое окно.
В него я передаю информацию из
главного без проблем. В новом окне
пользователь редактирует данные и на
нём есть 2 кнопки, одна закрывает
окно, а вторая - "Сохранить" и при её
нажатии надо передать значения из
дочерней формы в главную, а там уже
предпринимать дальнейшие действия с
этими значениями, проблема в том, что
дочерняя форма "отказывается" работать
с основной. Как это исправить?

Спасибо, [[@Константин25](/users/6990/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD25)](/users/6990/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD25).
Вот кое-что придумал, но кажется это уж чересчур заумно...

```
 ----  ``-Создаю статический класс

public static class Values
    {
        public static string V1;
        public static string V2;
//........
    }
```

На кнопке для отображения второй формы в главной форме пишу

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form_add = new Form_Add();
//Здесь передаю значения из главной в дочернюю и пишу это...
        Form_add.Dobavit+=Dobavlenie;
        Form_add.ShowDialog();

    }
void Dobavlenie(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = Values.V1;//В этой метке,например на главной  форме я 
        //получу значения из статического класса,
        // а в него внесу значения из дочерней формы
    }
```

В дочернем окне при нажатии кнопки пишу

```
    private void button_dobavit_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Values.V1= this.DatePicker1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Dobavit(sender, e);
        this.Close();
    }

    public event EventHandler Dobavit = delegate { };
```

Comment: Говорит - не буду и всё? :-) поконкретнее можно?

Comment: Та говорит "Денег давай! Просто так не буду работать" :) Я не могу увидеть главную форму, находясь в дочерней. (Читаю сообщение Константина25 там много примеров, должно получиться)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте тут и все поймете: [как передать данный из одной формы в другую?](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас точно определено отношение дочерняя - главная форма, то вы можете передать референс на главную форму в конструктор дочерней.

Дальше - тривиально, либо делайте изменяемые проперти главной формы как проперти с паблик сеттерами, либо инкапсулируйте логику изменения этих свойств в методы типа **ChangeXYZSettings.**

---

В любом случае, кстати говоря, это bad design, поскольку дочерняя форма обычно не должна знать ничего конкретного о главной форме и изменяемые данные стоит выносить в модель, откуда они уже будут подтянуты известным способом.

Comment: За что минус поставили?

Comment: Эт не я. Там инфы много...перерабатываю, пока я только извращённый вариант придумал